# How to develop apps for HP devices

Tags: tablet

How to develop apps for HP devices. If I want to develop apps for HP's slate or tablet, what all do I need to install and have knowledge of? Does it support J2ME?

Comment: are there specific HP devices you're targeting (ie: provide some more info about the specific devices)?

Comment: Actually, I am pretty new to this area but what I am looking for is something similar to iPad from Apple. I think HP has tablets and slates that are similar to iPad but I am not sure if they allow developing apps the way apple does. If yes do I need to have any specific Hardware like MAC for Apple. Also what all softwares do I need to install and learn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main programming languages for webOS apps are Javascript, and C (using the PDK).  You might be able to stuff code from almost any compiled language inside the PDK portion, but HP/Palm doesn't supply tools for that.